# Is there a way to move windows to different monitors based on which taskbar they are clicked on from?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, taskbar

So I have two monitors, and I wa wondering if there was a way to make it so that if I were to click an icon on the second monitor's taskbar, then the windows would move from the first monitor to the second. Basically, whichever monitor's taskbar is used the window will be moved to there.

Answer (score 1):

[DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/Features/WindowLocation/) seems to be able to do this:

> Each application can be configured using these settings:
>
> - **Monitor:** Which monitor you would like the application windows to open on. Optionally, you can choose to have the application windows
>     be moved to the monitor that currently has the mouse cursor.
> - **Mode:** Choose between "First Window Only" and "All Windows" for the selected application.
> - **Size:** Choose between "Original Size", "Maximize", "Minimize", "Centre", or "Span". You can also specify a Function to be run on the 
>     window instead of using the standard sizing modes.

---

**Disclaimer**: I am not in any way affiliated with DisplayFusion or Binary Fortress Software, nor am I an end user of the aforementioned software.